# Is there a Kitchen Sink for iOS 8 UI layouts?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, uikit, xcode6

I'm trying to get familiar with iOS 8. One of the things I found really useful while working with Sencha Touch is their Kitchen Sink (http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.3.1a/built-examples/kitchensink/index.html?platform=ios#demo/buttons)

Is there something like that for Xcode and iOS8 where I can quickly see and play with all available layouts and quickly see some related code?

Comment: The Apple HIG might help too: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has a sample code project that demonstrates nearly all the controls found in UIKit. See [UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) on the developer site.